# Windows 8.1 and signed driver problems

Tags: driver, windows-8.1, driver-signing

I have a driver which is signed using the steps in this link: 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

When i try to install this driver on Windows 8.1 it fails. The driver can install on all other Operating Systems.

When i restart the computer and disables driver signature enforcement and start the driver install then a message appears saying that the publisher of the driver is unkown and asks me if i want continue the install or not. If u choose to install then the driver is installed on Windows 8.1. So the problem must be something with the driver signature i guess.

Taken from the link: "The driver is marked as "Not Trusted" because Windows cannot validate the certificate against any of the trusted certificates in the per computer Trusted Root Certification Authorities store".

As this driver is meant to run on customer machines this problem is really annoying.

So:
Will this problem be solved if i make the driver marked as "Trusted" - and how do I do that?
Or does someone know an easier workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `/tr` instead of `/t` because I have experienced trouble with the `/tr` option as described in my article, [Practical Windows Code and Driver Signing](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/).

What exactly do you mean by "it fails"?  What error message do you get, or what unexpected behavior?  Could you post the .CAT file here so we can look at your signature?  Does your certificate your SHA1 or SHA2?  What about the CAT file and the signature of the CAT file?

You could consider buying a certificate instead of making one yourself.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about putting your certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities list and the Trusted Publishers list on all of your customers' computers.